# how to create an array in python for n*3

Tags: python, data-structures

given a number N I want to make three list of size N*3 such that
numbers should not be repeated
The size of each array should be N
How to do that?

for e.g : N= 2
`x =[1,2] y = [3,4] z = [5,6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a list from 3 ranges:

```py
def three_list(N:int) -> (list, list, list):
    return list(range(1,N + 1)), list(range(N + 1, 2 * N + 1)), list(range(2 * N + 1, 3 * N + 1))
```

Test run:

```py
three_list(4)
# output:
([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12])
```